# Hooks useState is formik - React

Tags: reactjs

I send the form through Formik and it works well for me.

Now I need to validate a data (check if a given data is valid) in the database, before submitting the form completely.

But the way I have done it so far, I am managing to validate the information given, but the number field of the form is completely empty.

Below is a summary of the code:

```
const ContactModal = ({ open, onClose, contactId, initialValues, onSave }) => {
  const initialState = {
    name: "",
    number: "",
    email: "",
  };

  const [contact, setContact] = useState(initialState);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (number !== "") {
      if (number.length > 11) {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          if (number !== "") {
            console.log(number);
          }
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
        };
      }
    }
  }, [number]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={contact}
        enableReinitialize={true}
        validationSchema={ContactSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            handleSaveContact(values);
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 400);
        }}
      >
        {({ values, errors, touched, isSubmitting }) => (
          <form>
            <Field as={TextField} label="Nome" name="name" autoFocus />
            <Field
              as={TextField}
              label="Número"
              name="number"
              placeholder="5513912344321"
              value={number}
              onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
            />
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactModal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform async validation. You can easily achieve that by providing a custom `validate` function to `<Formik>` component, or adding a `test` method that returns a Promise in your validation schema (defined with YUP for example).

Here is a gist of how it would look like:

```
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Formik } from "formik";

const FormFields = {
  name: "name",
  number: "number",
  email: "email"
};

const ContactSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  [FormFields.name]: Yup.string()
    .min(2, "Too Short!")
    .max(100, "Too Long!")
    .required("Required"),
  [FormFields.number]: Yup.string()
    .required("Required")
    .test("checkNumber", "number is invalid", (value) => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        // TODO: here do your API call with `value` instead.
        // This is just for testing purposes

        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
        const isValid = Math.round(Math.random());

        console.log(isValid);

        return resolve(isValid);
      });
    })
});

const ContactModal = ({ open, onClose, contactId, initialValues, onSave }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          [FormFields.name]: "",
          [FormFields.number]: "",
          [FormFields.email]: ""
        }}
        validationSchema={ContactSchema}
        enableReinitialize={true}
        validateOnBlur={false} // It will automatically validate onSubmit and on Change, but I am disable validation onBlur.
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          // TODO: submit your already validated values.
          console.log(values);
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              label="Nome"
              name={FormFields.name}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              value={formik.values[FormFields.name]}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
            />
            <TextField
              id={FormFields.number}
              label="Número"
              name={FormFields.number}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              placeholder="5513912344321"
              value={formik.values[FormFields.number]}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={
                formik.touched[FormFields.number] &&
                Boolean(formik.errors[FormFields.number])
              }
              helperText={
                formik.touched[FormFields.number] &&
                formik.errors[FormFields.number]
              }
            />
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you don't wanna use `yup`, you can provide an [async `validate` function to `Formik`](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#validate), just like this:

```
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Formik } from "formik";

const FormFields = {
  name: "name",
  number: "number",
  email: "email"
};

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const validate = (values) => {
  // Call your API instead of sleep.
  return sleep(2000).then(() => {
    const errors = {};

    const isNumberEven = values[FormFields.number] % 2 === 0;

    if (!isNumberEven) {
      errors[FormFields.number] = "Number must be even";
    }

    //...

    return errors;
  });
};

const ContactModal = ({ open, onClose, contactId, initialValues, onSave }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          [FormFields.name]: "",
          [FormFields.number]: "",
          [FormFields.email]: ""
        }}
        validate={validate}
        enableReinitialize={true}
        validateOnBlur={false} // It will automatically validate onSubmit and on Change, but I am disable validation onBlur.
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          // TODO: submit your already validated values.
          console.log(values);
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              label="Nome"
              name={FormFields.name}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              value={formik.values[FormFields.name]}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
            />
            <TextField
              id={FormFields.number}
              label="Número"
              name={FormFields.number}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              placeholder="5513912344321"
              value={formik.values[FormFields.number]}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={
                formik.touched[FormFields.number] &&
                Boolean(formik.errors[FormFields.number])
              }
              helperText={
                formik.touched[FormFields.number] &&
                formik.errors[FormFields.number]
              }
            />
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it well, but I need to make a request, sending the value of the number field in the request and in the return of that request, I will know whether or not I can send (save) the form.

In short: I want to enter a value in the numeric field and after a few milliseconds a request is made with the value of this field, if the return is true it means that I can proceed, fill in the other name field and click on save the form.

Comment: @WagnerFillio so basically what you want is async validation? You can achieve that easily providing either a custom `validate` function to Formik, or actually using your validation schema with YUP. I have updated my answer

Comment: yes, I want an asynchronous validation via API! but am I obliged to use YUP? thanks!

Comment: @WagnerFillio if you don't want to use yup (even though I highly recommend it since it plays nicely with Formik), you can just provide a custom `validate` function to `Formik` component. Check updated answer